# Why is my react import function not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import a function from another file in react, but it says that my function is not defined

in Todolist.js:

```
import React from 'react';
export default function TodoList() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In App.js:

```
//import react from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import {Todolist} from "./TodoList";


function App() {
  return (
    <TodoList />
  )
}

export default App;
```

the result:

> WARNING in src\App.js
> Line 3:9:  'Todolist' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

> ERROR in src\App.js
> Line 8:6:  'TodoList' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: You are default exporting the component and then import it as named import: please check link:[import-export](https://javascript.info/import-export).

Comment: import {Todolist} from "./TodoList"; replace this with import {TodoList} from './Todolist';

Answer (score 3):

change to default import

```
import Todolist from "./TodoList";
```

Answer (score 2):

because you use `export default ....`

the import should be like this.

`import Todolist from "./TodoList";`

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to do import/export in es6:**

1. Default Export (Can have only one default export)
2. Named Export (Can have zero or more named exports)

---

If a component/module is a default export then it is required to import it without brackets.

```
// Default Export.
export default App;

// Import above default export without curly braces.
import App from './path/to/your/App';
```

If a component/module is a named export then it is required to import it with curly braces.

```
// Named Export.
export A = 'Test String';
export {YourComponent};

// Import above named export with curly braces.
import {A} from './path/to/A';
import {YourComponent} from './path/to/YourComponent';
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned you need to look at the named/ default export choice. Also, there is a typo in the import of TodoList - the 'l' should be capitalised.